# Content displaying issues

Tags: html, css, position, inline

I am having an issue aligning two different elements to where they are parallel horizontally. I am wanting the second grid `right_service_wrap` to appear on the right side of the page just like the `left_service_wrap`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong that the float right is appearing below the `left_service_wrap`.

Anyone have any ideas??

```css
.left_service_wrap {

}
.right_service_wrap {
 float: right;
 display: inline;
}
.title_left {
 margin-left: 20%;
}
.title_right {
 
}
.service_wrapper {
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 15px;
 width: 20%;
}
.service_list {
 margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_service_wrap">
 <div class="title_left">A LIST OF OUR SERVICES</div>
 <div class="service_list">
  <div class="service_wrapper">
   <div class="service_title">Flooring</div>
   <div class="service_description">The best floors!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
   <div class="service_title">Roofing</div>
   <div class="service_description">Your roof will be perfect!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
   <div class="service_title">Siding</div>
   <div class="service_description">mmmm siding.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
   <div class="service_title">Paint</div>
   <div class="service_description">Fabulous paint!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
   <div class="service_title">Kitchen Remodels</div>
   <div class="service_description">Pretty kitchen.</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div> 
<div class="right_service_wrap">
 <div class="title_right">A LIST OF OUR SERVICES</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width of both to 50% and do:

```
.left_service_wrap {
   float:left;
   width:50%;
}
.right_service_wrap {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}
```

Working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/usrce45v/

Consider that your requirement of an extra left margin to be applied to the left container requires you to rearrange the width of both left and right containers. So, for a `left-margin` of 20% the equation becomes:
whole parent width (100%) minus margin (20%), half the result (40%).

Comment: I added width: 50%; to each one, but it still isn't positioning correctly. I wanted the left side columns to start at the margin-left: 20%; area. It is pushing it way over and making my borders smaller than they should be

Comment: My site can be seen in the other answer.

Comment: Do I have to adjust all of my children divs to the 50%, is that why they are smaller than what they used to be?

Comment: In such case setting the width of both container to 40%, that means (100 - 20)/2, should do the job.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. That issue was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I fully understand your question, but if it is what I think, you have to add `float: left` to the  `.left_service_wrap` class rule. (and define a width for it that allows the elements in it to be displayed as desired)

Comment: Ok, that brings it up, but it makes it completely squished. Here is the live site: http://realtorcatch.com/service

Comment: I added `width: 50%; to each one, but it still isn't positioning correctly. I wanted the left side columns to start at the `margin-left: 20%; area. It is pushing it way over and making my borders smaller than they should be.

Comment: keep in mind that percentage width values always relate to the parent element - you'll have to adjust those, for example give `.product_wrapper`and `.service_wrapper` both `width: 50%;`